# Increase Size of Heatmap in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

My heatmap does not change size when changing the figsize parameters. I use Latex style for my plots and have set general parameters for the plots:

```
# Ploting:
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
plt.style.reload_library()
plt.style.use('science')
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7.39, 4.567) 
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.5
matplotlib.rcParams["legend.frameon"] = True # When you need legend background color
matplotlib.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 0.2
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['grid.color'] = '#b5b5b5'
matplotlib.rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = '-'
matplotlib.rcParams['grid.linewidth'] = 0.2
```

Here is the code for the actual heatmap:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,5))
im = ax.imshow(Granger, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none', norm=norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, extend='max')
cbar.cmap.set_over('green')
fig.axes[1].set_visible(False)
# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(Granger_colnames)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(Granger_rownames)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(Granger_colnames)
ax.set_yticklabels(Granger_rownames)

#plt.show()
plt.savefig("/content/drive/MyDrive/Plots/Granger.pdf")
```

I want to space out the rows and columns so that the text is better visible.

[image]

Comment: you hard set the figure size with `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7.39, 4.567) `, so change it. You also set the figure size in `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,5))`, so don't set both. I'm voting to close this as caused by a type / not reproducible.

Comment: You can, of course set both, but I think you want to make your figure taller, not wider (`figsize=(5, 16)`)